# Would the function be discontinous at $4$ in this case?

Tags: continuity

If the continuous interval is $[-2,4)$ and the domain is $[-4,4)$ for this function, can we say the function is discontinuous at $f(4)$?

If we sketch the graph, then there will be empty hold at $f(4)$.

Comment: If the point is not in the domain, it makes no sense to talk about continuity at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is simply not defined for $x=4$ thus it doesn't make sense inquire about continuity at that point.

Think, as an example, to $\log x$ that is defined on $(0,+\infty)$ and is continuos for all $x$ in the domain.